# Django - unit test with sites framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I've tried to run unittest with sites framework.
This is the test function:

```
def test_main(self):
  response = self.client.get('/')
  self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

and this is the command:

```
python2.7 manage.py test --settings=myproject.settings_01
```

But I've got an error because the test function doesn't know which site I want test. `--settings` doesn't work.

How should I say that I want test `SITE_ID=1`

Error:

```
======================================================================
enter code here`ERROR: test_main (sport.tests.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 216, in inner
    return test_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/torm/BookingSystem/sport/tests.py", line 12, in test_main
    response = self.client.get('/')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 470, in get
    **extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 286, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 358, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 440, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
    % (callback.__module__, view_name))
ValueError: The view system.views.main_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead
```

Main function:

```
def main_page(request):
    site = get_current_site(request)

    if site.name == 'sport':
        return sport.views.main_page(request)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I didn't change name of site in test database.

```
def setUp(self):
    site = Site.objects.get(id=1)
    site.name = 'sport'
    site.save()
```

When I add this code to test class everything works fine.

Comment: To save anyone else a google, this is just missing the import: `from django.contrib.sites.models import Site`

Answer (score 0):

Does your settings_01.py is in /project folder ? And please give us the trace of error.

You can specified wich project or app you want to test by args.

Exemple :

```
python2.7 manage.py test myproject.myapp --settings="myproject.settings_01"
```

Comment: When I run server everything works, only test doesn't.

Comment: Please paste the trace of error and i will try to help you with more accuracy